# Evaluating $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin x + \sqrt{\sin^2x+e^{\cos x}})dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Integral
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin x + \sqrt{\sin^2x+e^{\cos x}})dx.$$
I m stuck with this problem and couldnt find anywhere hint how to solve this bad boy.

Comment: Hint: 1) $\sin x$ is an odd function 2) $(\sqrt{u+v^2} + v)(\sqrt{u+v^2}-v) = u$

Comment: When you finish the exercise you can post your own answer. If you're still stuck, edit your question with the things you have tried and we can help you :D

Answer (score 2):

Split it into $\int_{-\pi/2}^{0}+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}$ and substitute $x\mapsto-x$ in the first of these integrals. You get a simple integral as a result: $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(-\sin x+\sqrt{\sin^2 x+e^{\cos x}})\,dx\\+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin x+\sqrt{\sin^2 x+e^{\cos x}})\,dx\\=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos x\,dx=1.$$

Comment: You could acknowledge achille hui's comment as you seem to be using it without any explanation.